# Does SQL's EXISTS function select duplicates? (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

`t1` has all the credits of each person in a given ORACLE database. Each person is identified by `ID`. `t2` contains the people I need to select from `t1`.

To do this, I tried the following:

```sql
select
    ID,
    capital,
    balance
from
    t1
where
    exists (
        select ID
        from t2
        where t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

My problem is that `t2` has duplicate `ID`s. So for example, if `ID = 2` has 3 credits and she is repeated 4 times in `t2`, will the above query select each of her credits 4 times? That is, will I have 3 x 4 credits for `ID = 2`?

Typically, I would count the duplicate credits from the result, but I currently do not have a unique identifier for the selected credits. This is the reason I am asking this here rather than trying a grouped by count from the query's result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The query that you have written only returns rows from `t1`.  You cannot multiply rows using a `where` clause (well, almost never and not in `Oracle`).

One reason for using `exists` or `in` is so you don't have to worry about duplicates, the way you would need to worry with a `join`.

Answer (score 2):

No - think of `exists` as a True/False function. True: returns >0 rows; False: returns 0 rows. So it doesn't matter if there are duplicates.